# How does linux manage concurrent file writing and renaming?

Tags: c++, linux, file, io

I have two programs in C++, one write to a file, and the other renames it (to lock it, but make the first to be able to write as well) and works on it. My question is, that is it possible? In a scenario, while the first is writing, and the second tries to rename the same file, what will happen? I need a rock solid solution with all the corner cases covered. Small databases seem too complicated for this little task. I need persistence because there might be unsuccessful runs of the second program and have to try again.

Comment: Renaming files is atomic (if within the same filesystem).

Comment: "I need a rock solid solution with all the corner cases covered" - I don't think you can get one within the constraints you provide.

Comment: Directory entries are not files.  You use the name to access the file, but once 'open' completes the name used to access the file is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

File locking in Linux is messy.  There's a few different techniques but they are all advisory locks, meaning that other processes can ignore the lock simply by no checking for one.  **You cannot prevent another process from writing to a file if the process doesn't check for a lock.**

I'll point to the existence of [flock()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) but this is still only advisory and doesn't work well with remote file systems.

---

The problem is that there are three separate concepts which act independently in Linux:

- File data - the actual data "on disk".
- File names - these are just handles in a directory structure providing access to open a file.
- File descriptors / file descriptions - A processes own reference onto file data once the file has been opened.

Two processes can have a file description onto the same file (both have it open at the same time).  If the file is renamed, it only affects future calls to [open()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open); renaming and even deleting a file only removes the old file name.  Actually an open file can be deleted and the data will stay on disk until the the open file description is closed.

---

If you are in control of all programs writing to a file then one common way to lock it is to create a lock file with [both O_CREAT and O_EXCL](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).  Ie: to lock `my_file.txt` you create a `.my_file.txt.lock`.  If the lock file already exists, this will fail.  But this still requires another process to check first.

This is often accepted as the most effective type of lock available.

---

Your solution of renaming first will not be much better.  If another process opens the file before yours has renamed it, the other process will carry on writing to the file and never know any different.

Answer (score 0):

From [rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), my bolding:

> rename() renames a file, moving it between directories if required.
> Any other hard links to the file (as created using link(2)) are
> unaffected.  **Open file descriptors for oldpath are** also **unaffected**.